# C++ File IO: read input of "29.0" to double but output is "29", i.e. ".0" removed

Tags: c++, io, double

I use the following code to read the data from a file.
The input file is

`29.0 45.0 0.0 15.0`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string fileName;
    cout << "input the file: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    double temp1=0.0, temp2=0.0, temp3=0.0, temp4=0.0;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(!fin.is_open()){
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl; 
    }

    fin >> temp1 >>temp2 >>temp3 >>temp4;

    cout << temp1 << " " << temp2 << " " << temp3 <<" " <<temp4 <<endl;
    fin.close();
}
```

But I got `29 45 0 15` instead of `29.0 45.0 0.0 15.0`

If I changed the data file to `29.1 45.1 0.1 15.1`, then I got exactly `29.1 45.1 0.1 15.1`.

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Why shouldn't it print 29.0? 29.0 and 29 are the same number, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the ".0" etc. if and only if it appeared in the input, you need to read the values as text - e.g. into `std::string`s.  When you read into `double`s, the logical value is stored (as best as it can be in cases where the exact textual value doesn't have a bitwise representation in a `double`, such as say `0.1` which can't be represented exactly), and it's up to the output code to guess at how many digits you'd like - by default it guesses that a trailing ".0" is of no value to the reader.

You can change that with io manipulators like [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) - both pages have useful examples, the `setprecision` one reproduced below for convenience:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    const long double pi = std::acos(-1.L);
    std::cout << "default precision (6): " << pi << '\n'
              << "std::precision(10):    " << std::setprecision(10) << pi << '\n'
              << "max precision:         "
              << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1)
              << pi << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
default precision (6): 3.14159
std::precision(10):    3.141592654
max precision:         3.141592653589793239
```